# ERROR: variable name not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, file-io

I have written the following code, but i get an error saying: name 'acc' not defined. How do i fix it?

```
 import csv

    with open(r"C:\Users\garfield\Python27\trial.txt") as file,     open(r"C:\Users\garfield\Python27\outp.csv", "a+") as f:
 x=file.read()
 m=x.split()
 writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter =",",quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
 for i in range(len(m)-1):
    if "ACCESSION" in m[i]:
        acc=m[i+1]
    if '/host' in m[i]:
        host1=m[i].split('/host')[1].split('\n')[0]
        host2=m[i+1]
        host=host1+" "+host2 
    if "5'UTR" in m[i]:
        utr=m[i+1]
    data=[acc,host,utr]
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: You should post an MCVE so that people can reproduce your problem. But make sure `acc` is defined for all paths that lead to `data=[acc,host,utr]`.

Comment: Are you trying to write a single row into the csv?

Comment: You are doing some weird things there. You read the whole file then split it. That's probably not doing what you want it to do. And then you check for those three strings with `if`s, but if any of them is not found in the first `m[i]`, you'll get that error. And even if you didn't, I'm not sure that's what you want either, because those values will persist until another of those strings is found (that can make sense if you're using the strings as flags).

Answer (score 0):

From your code seems like, you are trying to parse the complete file , create `acc` / `utr` / `host` variables from it, and then write it into the csv, to me it looks like what you want to write is a single row in the csv, after the complete inputfile as been processed, if so, the indentation for the lines -

```
data=[acc,host,utr]
writer.writerow(data)
```

is wrong, it should be indented outside the `for` loop, not inside it Example -

```
for i in range(len(m)-1):
    if "ACCESSION" in m[i]:
        acc=m[i+1]
    if '/host' in m[i]:
        host1=m[i].split('/host')[1].split('\n')[0]
        host2=m[i+1]
        host=host1+" "+host2 
    if "5'UTR" in m[i]:
        utr=m[i+1]
writer.writerow([acc,host,utr])            #there is no need for an extra variable here.
```

Also, you should put some default value for all three variables to handle cases when the particular lines are not found in the file.